# PHP Array to string

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting array from one of my network devices and I don't understand how I can get output array to string.

I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.1] => STRING: "sensitive_data_1"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.2] => STRING: "sensitive_data_2"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.3] => STRING: "sensitive_data_3"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.4] => STRING: "sensitive_data_4"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.5] => STRING: "sensitive_data_5"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.6] => STRING: "sensitive_data_6"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.7] => STRING: "sensitive_data_7"
    [iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.8] => STRING: "sensitive_data_8"
)
```

And I don't know how can I get only **sensitive_data_1-8** to my values.

*EDIT*: I want output like:

```
$value[1] = "sensitive_data_1";
$value[2] = "sensitive_data_2";
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $string) echo $string;` Like this?

Comment: Yes but i get result:

`STRING: "sensitive_data_1"
STRING: "sensitive_data_2"
STRING: "sensitive_data_3"
STRING: "sensitive_data_4"
STRING: "sensitive_data_5"
STRING: "sensitive_data_6"
STRING: "sensitive_data_7"
STRING: "sensitive_data_8"`

And when i try echo only one array like `echo $string[1]` i get some TTTTT or GGGGG as print.

Comment: You need `sensitive_data_1sensitive_data_2sensitive_data_3.....`, right ? Tell the full output you need.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - yes!

Comment: @mTechLabs, do you get that big array in PHP ?

Comment: How do you want the output? Edit your question and add a expected output.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - yes again :D

Comment: @Andreas ok, done.

Comment: Value[1] is not "sensitive_data_1". Value[0] is though. Is that really how you want the output, or do you want to manipulate the array?

Comment: @Andreas There really isn't any "[1]" (nor "[0]") at all in this array…

Comment: True, but I figured he simplified the output.

Comment: @mTech So the array actually contains the values `'STRING: "sensitive_data_1"'`? So then you want to remove the 'STRING: "' and '"' from it…?

Comment: @mTechLabs, that is not any valid PHP array.

Comment: @deceze yes that i need

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed i get that array from my network devices i can't get any other..

Comment: @mTechLabs, how do you get that ? Through any ajax call ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, It doesn't seem to be an invalid array. It was output using `print_r` to something like this `$array = array('iso.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.12.2.4.1.3.1' => 'STRING: "sensitive_data_1"');
`

Comment: @Emerald, we cannot work with the `print_r` value, id the original array is posted, the problem can be easily solved

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, Agree but it's beyond our control. It's in the OP's control to post whether the original array or the output from the print_r. You should've easily known it's the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function then [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the portion of array's string value

```
$array = array(
    // Your array data here
);

$value = array_map(function($e) {
    return substr($e, 8);
}, $array);

echo $value[0]; // Outputs "sensitive_data_1"
echo $value[1]; // Outputs "sensitive_data_2"
```

Simple work around if you want to start with `$value[1]`

```
$array = array(
    // Your array data here
);

$value = array_map(function($e) {
    return substr($e, 8);
}, $array);

array_unshift($value, ''); // Add dummy data
unset($value[0]);          // Remove dummy data
echo $value[1];            // Outputs: "sensitive_data_1"
echo $value[2];            // Outputs: "sensitive_data_2"
```

Comment: You would probably want to remove the `"` as well.

Comment: Thanks it help me!

Comment: @deceze yes but i can that my self.

Comment: Array_map() return keys to $value so it's not index array so you can't access $value[0] you have to convert array to index array by using array_values()
Check your own demo here https://3v4l.org/T5eB9